# Are there any difficulty settings in Stray?

Tags: stray

I'm playing Stray with my wife and she's had a hard time getting past the first encounter with the mite-things, called Zurks. We eventually got past the section, but not before dying enough times to limit the fun we're having in the game.

Is there a difficulty setting that might make my cat more resilient to the Zurks? Or if not, is there an easier way to escape the mites?

Comment: This is from someone who've completed (took all the achievements) the game... to be honest, that first encounter was hardest part in this game. Everything else is just some puzzle, and cat.

Comment: My wife doesn't really play video games and, while we finished it, she struggled with nearly every encounter with the Zurks. The security drones were OK though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there are no difficulty settings in it.

Answer (score 0):

You can meow to lure them away from where you need to progress, for a while.